# Accessing data from class selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

Currently trying to get the data which is stored in this class using selenium and print it into console.

`<h3 class="tiktok-dvof16-AuthorTitle e10yw27c0">allawi_9</h3>`

I tried  `print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tiktok-dvof16-AuthorTitle e10yw27c0"))`
I also tried adding .text at the end, however you cant do that on a list obj. (And the returned list is empty may I add.

However, it just returns an empty list. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great!

Comment: The entry you've circled has `tiktok-dvof16-AuthorTitle`.  Why are you looking for `AuthorAnchor`?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. `tiktok-dvof16-AuthorTitle e10yw27c0` even when using this, it still returns an empty list.

Comment: I guess the element is inside iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the element value is unique on the page you can use

```
myelemnt = driver.find_element_by_name('Some text')
myelement.print()
```

if not you can use X-path for this like

```
myelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]')
myelement.print()
```

if that doesnt worked use Full x-path

```
myelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[2]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]')
myelement.print()
```

for getting the x-path/full x-path simple just right-click on the element on the google chrome developer tools and click on Copy then  x-path / full x-path
[image]